# Duplicate Line command in TeXShop for Mac

Tags: macros, mac, texshop

I'm a quite new user of LaTeX and one thing I miss in TeXShop on mac is a "Duplicate Line"-command, espacially when writing mathematical derivations. It's my impression that it is possible to create a macro that does the trick, but unfortunately my programming skills are not that good, so does anyone have a solution?

I found this solution for TextWrangler (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/textwrangler/Orei3W7bsV4/kAGwnv9R_owJ). Are there a simple way of connecting the Applescript to TeXShop or does anyone have a script for the TeXShop macro editor?

Thanks

vegaso

Comment: TeXShop is also fully (and directly) compatible with Applescript. Among the macros designed for TeXShop with its macro editor there are a lot written in this language. I don't know much of Applescript myself, but it is likely that the script designed for TextWrangler also works with TeXShop. Obviously you'll have to replace "TextWrangler" by "TeXShop" in the contents of this script :-)

Comment: You can adapt my answer given in [Texshop macro for braces](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270588/texshop-macro-for-braces) and use `#SEL##SEL##INS#` fro the code. The `#SEL#` represents the selected text so you'll need to select the line and then this will duplicate the line for you.